# Why isn't $\mathcal D$ a sigma-algebra?

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

I came across the statement that if $(\Omega, \mathcal F, \mathbb P)$ is a probability space and $E \in \mathcal F$ then $$\mathcal D := \{ A \in \mathcal F \mid A \text{ and } E \text{ are independent} \}$$ is a Dynkin system. I guess that $\mathcal D$ is not a sigma-algebra yet I can't find a counterexample. Thus, we'd need a sequence $(A_n)$ such that each $A_n$ is independent from $E$ yet their union isn't.

I've tried some simple constructions on $[0,1]$ with Borel and Lebesgue yet it didn't help.

Any hints are hugely appreciated.

Comment: That triple is a measure space, not a sigma algebra. The middle component is the sigma algebra.

Comment: @Mr.Fry: many thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A Dynkin system is a $\sigma$-algebra iff it is stable under finite intersections. Is your family stable under finite intersections?

Comment: Oh, how interesting! Say, we're in $([0,1], \mathcal B, \lambda)$ and $E=\left[0, \frac{1}{2} \right], A_1=\left[0, \frac{1}{4} \right]\cup \left[\frac{3}{4}, 1 \right], A_2 = \left[\frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{2} \right]\cup \left[\frac{3}{4}, 1 \right]$. Is that what you mean? Is there any simpler example?